# Creating a unique verification code from a single number?

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, email-verification

I am making a plugin that provides a form, letting anyone submit a post to my Wordpress site (custom post type). I am looking for a very basic means of deterring bots/spammers though, so I want to e-mail a confirmation code that they can click and change the status to Published.

I would prefer not to store anything in the database, so I was thinking of just sending something like "verification.php?id=12", where the ID is the post ID. That is pretty obvious though, so I would like to make that single number look more complex, then "decrypt" it when the link is clicked to reveal the actual Post ID.

Pseudo Code:

```
If ($_GET['veriID'] != '')
$lastchar = substr($_GET['veriID'], -1);
publish_post($lastchar);
```

What would be some options to achieve this? Should I just generate a random string and append the post ID to the end or is there a better method?

Comment: Pass two parameters. id=12 and hash=X. Set the value of X to the result of an algorithm that uses a salt and also the id. You can then check in your code if the hash supplied matches the hash you expect

Comment: @chris Using an HMAC rather than directly hashing would be even better.

Comment: That sounds perfect Chris, could you provide an example of that? I would gladly accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HMAC to authenticate the request. The resulting url will look like the following:

```
.../verification.php?post=12&hash=5f13532e49447facaa3dce9080bfffec3c6731eca6b4d590670dd0b1137e7476
```

To generate the hash, the [HMAC algorithm](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) is used. This has the advantage that a secret value is used. Therefore the value cannot be computed by the message (the post id) alone.

Code to generate the hash value:

```
define('secret', 'really super secret value');

$post_id = 12;

// Get the hash
echo hash_hmac('sha256', $post_id, secret);
```

You can store the secret in a constant value or better: one per plugin-installation.

Since you can always compute the hash from the post-id, no data needs to be stored in a database.

Answer (score 1):

You could always encode the post ID as base64, then decode on confirmation.

This will be relatively obvious to most programmers, but not necessarily to the average user.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Recommending base64 for anything related to security is a no-no, regardless of how basic.

Comment: Not to mention that this "verification code" only contains two characters.

Comment: @Luke but the OP want somthing recoverable so you should consider how basic it is so your comment makes no sense given that the OP wrote he wants it to be very basic without storing the code.

Comment: @AmrBerag There is no need for it to be recoverable.  See the other answer.  And if it did need to be recoverable, actually encrypting it would be the correct way to proceed.  Base64 is not for security.  No exceptions.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for, basically just making it look a little more complicated as I didn't need any security. The HMAC approach above remains about as simple and does add a bit of security though so I have chosen that as best answer.

Comment: @AidanKnight You do need security, it would be incredibly simple to write a bot to get around this approach.  The HMAC approach, however, would be impossible.  So you do need security ;)

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Yes you are right, I will be using that approach :)

Answer (score -2):

A simple way would be adding a custom field to your post and store a random code in it like this

```
$code = '';
 for ( $i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i ) {
  $code .=  chr(rand(97,122)) . rand(0,9);
 }
```

Its true this is stored in the db post meta but you will not be explicitly doing it instead you do it the same way WP works by using:

```
get_post_meta(  $post_id,  $key, true );
```

Comment: This method requires database access.  The accepted answer is more appropriate for the given scenario.  Additionally, if you're going to generate a random token, use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`.  It's cryptographically secure and generally preferred for this kind of thing.